# unable connect to java app running on server (Heroku)

Tags: java, heroku, server

I deployed my app on Heroku. It is  a simple app that will throw back the message sent from its client version (running on my PC) back to the client. My server app prints the IP address of the machine it's running on so I can connect to it from  my client . I do get to see the IP address of Heroku machine when I deploy and run it. However, I am not able to connect to it from my client version using that IP address(Connection timed out) . I have allowed the port I am using in my firewalls. I don't understand what I am doing wrong .

Pls help me solve it.

If you need to see my code let me know ( the  app works fine locally on different terminals so I don't think it has a problem).

Answer (score 1):

Your Heroku dyno (an isolated server) is behind a router. You can't use the IP address to connect to it.

Instead, you the URL https://[appname].herokuapp.com where "[appname]" is the name of your app.

You can also run `heroku open` from the command line.